# Querying on a max date in a precise range and getting selected fields in the results

Tags: date, elasticsearch, max, filtering, aggregate

I'm new to Elastic Search and i'm facing some problems when using multiple filters (particularly with a "max") on a query

I'm currently working on a huge database indexed by Elastic Search.
There's a lot of documents, each document is all the informations about one particular server.

A soft is sporadically running on these servers and create a new document with updated informations.

So, information is stored like :

```
Id : item1
ITDiscovery_Date : 29/03/2016
Information1 : ...
Information2 : ...

Id : item1
ITDiscovery_Date : 12/03/2016
Information1 : ...
Information2 : ...

Id : item2
ITDiscovery_Date : 16/02/2016
Information1 : ...
Information2 : ...

Id : item2 
ITDiscovery_Date : 27/01/2016 
Information1 : ...
Information2 : ...
```

And so on

My problem is the following :

I'm trying to get the most recent informations about one particular server. For this, I want to filter first the name of the server (e.g. item456), then get all the documents of this server in a particular date range (e.g. from 01/01/2015 to today), then filter on the max date, in order to get the most recent informations, and get in result the selected fields (e.g. Information15, Information28 and Information68)

I've tried some different requests but can't get it to work, for exemple this one :

```
{
  "fields": [
    "Information15",
    "Information28",
    "Information68"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Id": "item456"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "date_range": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "ITDiscovery_Date": {
            "gte": 1420066800000,
            "lte": 1459241770000
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_date": {
          "max": {
            "field": "ITDiscovery_Date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns all the documents in the selected date range and not only the one with the max date :

```
{
  "took" : 34,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 982,
    "successful" : 982,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 33,
    "max_score" : 15.364556,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "itdiscovery_2016.03.02",
      "_type" : "default",
      "_id" : "item456",
      "_score" : 15.364556,
      "fields" : {
        "Information15" : [ "XXX" ],
        "Information28" : [ "XXX" ],
        "Information68" : [ "XXX" ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "itdiscovery_2016.03.23",
      "_type" : "default",
      "_id" : "item456",
      "_score" : 15.359651,
      "fields" : {
        "Information15" : [ "XXX" ],
        "Information28" : [ "XXX" ],
        "Information68" : [ "XXX" ]
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    ...
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "date_range" : {
      "doc_count" : 33,
      "max_date" : {
        "value" : 1.45922382E12
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a (temporary) solution.

I use a filtered query to get the results in the specified range date.
Then I use sort on the ITDiscovery_Date and limit the results to 1.
It gets the most recent result as expected.

For example :

```
{
  "fields": [
    "Information15",
    "Information28",
    "Information68"
  ],
  "sort": [
    { "ITDiscovery.Date.raw": {"order": "desc", "ignore_unmapped" : true}}
  ],
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "Id: item456",
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "ITDiscovery.Date": {
                  "gte": 1420070400000,
                  "lte": 1459241770000
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```